# Add a JS class called Employee and create methods to sort employees by different parameters and to filter by age

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

This code is what I got and it totally confuses me what next I can do. If someone can help me then that would be great.

```
class Employee{
    
}
let employeeList = [
    {
       "id":1,
      "name": "Shivam",
      "salary":700000,
      "age":26
    },
    {
       "id":2,
      "name": "om",
      "salary":600000,
      "age":22
    },
    {
       "id":3,
      "name": "shubham",
      "salary":500000,
      "age":42
    },
    {
       "id":4,
      "name": "Ram",
      "salary":400000 ,
      "age":32
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you know their age?

Comment: @DaveNewton added age.....can you just solve this according to your knowledge, that would be very helpful for me

Comment: What specific issue are you having?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be more concise with your questions as it's really difficult to tell what you want exactly, I have written some code that might help you but I don't know how helpful it actually would be as I don't know if it's what you are looking for, let me know if you need explanations for any of these, be it the sort method or class or anything, good day and take care

```
class Employee {
    constructor(id, name, salary, age){
        this.id=id;
        this.name =name;
        this.salary= salary;
        this.age = age;
    }
}


const filterAge = (employeeList, minAge, maxAge) => {
  return employeeList.filter((employee) => employee.age >= minAge && employee.age <= maxAge);
};

const sortEmployee=(employeeList, sortBy)=>{
    switch (sortBy){
        case 1:
        //by id
        return employeeList.sort((a,b)=>a.id>b.id?1:-1);
        case 2:
        //by name
        return employeeList.sort((a,b)=>a.name>b.name?1:-1);
        case 3:
        //by salary
        return employeeList.sort((a,b)=>a.salary - b.salary);
        case 4:
        //by age
        return employeeList.sort((a,b)=>a.age - b.age);
        
        default:
        return employeeList;
        
    }
    
}

const employeeList = [
    new Employee(1,"Shivam", 700000, 26),
    new Employee (2,"Om",600000, 22),
    new Employee (3,"Shubham", 500000,42),
    new Employee (4, "Ram", 400000,32)
];

const sortedEmployee = sortEmployee(employeeList,2);
const filteredEmployee = filterAge(employeeList, 20, 40);

console.log(sortedEmployee)
console.log(filteredEmployee)
```